# Using arguments passed as context in forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a view which passes a context to a template like this

```
 context = {
     'items': items,
 }
```

items is a collection/list of items.
In my template, I list all of these items and create a form with a button for each of them. Now I want to be able to do something with each of them individually and the form looks something like this:

```
<form action= "{% url 'app:page' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="something" value="{{item.id}}"/>
    <button type="submit">ButtonCaption</button>
</form>
```

I want to get the information, which item id has been chosen, to the view for the page. I'd normally do it with forms.Form, but in this case I rely on something chosen in the template. How do I get the {{item.id}} to my view?

Comment: Could you please show us your view? What kind of data are you posting? Is it check boxes or radio buttons, I mean is it Boolean data?

Comment: @FazilZaid I posted the solution to my question below. I didn't know that, as intuitive as it is, you can create Form objects with existing forms from the request as parameter, without having passed them as context before that. I tried to create a form object with the context like this:  
form = SomeForm()  
then pass it as context and still have it be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass multiple items want to make forms for each of them, you should call the for cycle like :

```
{% for item in items %}
    <form action= "{% url 'app:page' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="something" value="{{item.id}}"/>
        <button type="submit">ButtonCaption</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Otherwise you should pass only one item in your context like:

```
context = {'item': item,}
```

Or in your for cycle make some checkings like:

```
{% for item in items %}
{% if item.somevalue == 'somevalue' %}
   #some code if the value is true
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My problem was how to get the individual id back to the view. I managed to find a solution which was pretty obvioud. I'll post it as an answer to my question. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to create a new Form class with an input element with the same name as the name in the form. Then just post the form as it was and 
call this

```
form = SomeForm(request.POST)
```

and work with it as shown in the documentation.